# Get val of input of any variable with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form and I need to perform an action if a certain input is changed. In my jQuery, I have a three input fields set to a different variable e.g:

```
var workOrderInput = jQuery(".work-order-select input");
var eventSchedulerInput = jQuery(".event-scheduler .gchoice_2_13_0 #choice_2_13_0");
var eventSchedulerSelect = jQuery(".event-scheduler select");
```

In order to find out if the input changes, I am using:

```
jQuery([workOrderInput, eventSchedulerInput, eventSchedulerSelect]).each(function() {
    jQuery(this).change(function() {

    });
});
```

If one of the input fields changes, I would like to set a variable to the value of a hidden input field e.g.

```
jQuery([workOrderInput, eventSchedulerInput, eventSchedulerSelect]).each(function() {
    jQuery(this).change(function() {
        var totalCost = jQuery(".signup-cost #field_2_22 #input_2_22").val();
        console.log(totalCost);
    });
});
```

Right now, the totalCost variable gets set but only on the second click. For example, If I click on ".work-order-select input" nothing happen. Only when I click on another input does the variable get set and show up in the console.

Edit: Here is my HTML

```
<form>
    <div class="work-order-select">
        <input type="radio" name="wo1" value="14.99">
        <input type="radio" name="wo2" value="24.99">
        <input type="radio" name="wo2" value="34.99">
    </div>
    <div class="event-scheduler">
        <input type="radio" name="es1" value="44.99">
        <select name="es1" >
            <option value="Square Footage|0">Square Footage</option>
            <option value="Under 50,000($29.00/mt)|29">Under 50,000($29.00/mt)</option
            <option value="Under 75,000($49.00/mt)|49">Under 75,000($49.00/mt)</option>
            <option value="Under 100,000($59.00/mt)|59">Under 100,000($59.00/mt)</option>      
        </select>
    <div>
    <div>
        <span class="total"></span>
        <input type="hidden" id="input_2_22" value="49.99">
    </div>
</form>
```

Right now, as soon as one of the radio buttons are select, or the drop down changes, the input value of #input_2_22 is updated.

Using mouseup() also works...kind of. If I use:

```
jQuery([workOrderInput, eventSchedulerInput, eventSchedulerSelect]).each(function() {
    jQuery(this).mouseup(function() {
        var totalCost = jQuery(".signup-cost #field_2_22 #input_2_22").val();
        console.log(totalCost);
    });
});
```

The first radio button that is select returns nothing. It's literally an empty line in Chrome's web inspector. The second time I click on a radio button, the value of the previous radio button I clicked on is shown.

Edit 2: All of the above is fixed with:

```
jQuery("#choice_2_13_0, #choice_2_10_0, #choice_2_10_1, #choice_2_10_2").addClass("discount-class");

jQuery(".discount-class").change(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var totalCost = jQuery(".signup-cost #input_2_22").val();
        var totalDiscount = (totalCost * .2).toFixed(2);
        var afterDiscount = (totalCost - totalDiscount).toFixed(2);
        console.log(totalDiscount);
        jQuery("#input_2_23").val(totalDiscount);
    }, 1000);
});
```

Now, I only need the change function to fire if one of the "wo" radio buttons are selected and the select value does not equal "Square Footage|0". With no luck I'm trying:

```
if (jQuery(".discount-class").is(':checked') && jQuery("#input_2_14").val != 'Square Footage|0') {
```

Comment: It depends what element `jQuery(".signup-cost #field_2_22 #input_2_22")` represents.

Comment: It's a hidden input field.

Comment: According to the code you've provided, it doesn't look as though `totalCost` would change, unless you've logic elsewhere.

Comment: Since all `id`'s on the page are supposed to be unique, then why wouldn't you simply use `jQuery("#input_2_22")`?  You can't get any more specific than grabbing the exact element.

Comment: @user715564, it would be most beneficial to see the HTML associated with your JavaScript. Also `".signup-cost #field_2_22 #input_2_22"` is selecting on 2 id's this is most definitely an issue.

Comment: .change() is triggered after the input loses focus, so if you type in one input, and leave your cursor in that input, the totalCost variable wont change until you click outside of that input. if you want something to happen while you type, use something like .keyup(), .keydown() instead of .change()

Comment: @robbmj, how is that an issue? ... it's simply selecting an `id` that is a descendant of another `id`, which is a descendant of a `class`.  Very verbose and superfluous, but not an error.

Comment: id's should be unique to a page it doesn't make sense to select them in this manner.

Comment: @robbmj, I know it doesn't make sense and I already made that comment.  Just because it doesn't make sense, doesn't mean it's a technical problem.  `.signup-cost #field_2_22 #input_2_22` simply means `#input_2_22` inside of `#field_2_22` inside of `.signup-cost`... nothing illegal  about that.

Comment: OP, you need to show us the relevant HTML so we can reproduce.

Comment: I'm working with the wordpress plugin gravity forms but I will provide what I can.

Comment: Why not just attach the event handler to `jQuery([workOrderInput, eventSchedulerInput, eventSchedulerSelect])` instead of wrapping it in an `each()` call? Or for that matter, just concatenate the selectors. Or for that matter, add a class to all of the elements and use that, as @DelightedD0D suggests? Adding event handlers in a loop is bad practice.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan unless you want to bind to different events based on some variable, like the element type, which actually seems to be what to OP needs given they appear to have different element types

Comment: @DelightedD0D, except then you would just assign those handlers separately, not in a loop. The loop is completely unnecessary, since he already has the three elements in question.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan true, with the way they have it now, though I would get rid of all those and just use one class, in which case you would need the loop...or just use a different class for each element type...either way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably give all of your elements the same class and bind to them that way.

```js
jQuery('.myElements').change(function() {
  if (jQuery('#es1').val() != "Square Footage|0") {
    setTimeout(function() {
      var totalCost = jQuery("#input_2_22").val();
      jQuery('#test').append(totalCost + '<br>')
      console.log(totalCost);
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="work-order-select">
    <input type="radio" class="myElements" name="wo1" value="14.99">
    <input type="radio" class="myElements" name="wo2" value="24.99">
    <input type="radio" class="myElements" name="wo2" value="34.99">
  </div>
  <div class="event-scheduler">
    <input type="radio" class="myElements" name="es1" value="44.99">
    <select name="es1" id="es1" class="myElements">
      <option value="Square Footage|0">Square Footage</option>
      <option value="Under 50,000($29.00/mt)|29">Under 50,000($29.00/mt)</option <option value="Under 75,000($49.00/mt)|49">Under 75,000($49.00/mt)</option>
      <option value="Under 100,000($59.00/mt)|59">Under 100,000($59.00/mt)</option>
    </select>
    <div>
      <div>
        <span class="total"></span>
        <input type="hidden" id="input_2_22" value="49.99">
      </div>
</form>

<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: No, that's not what I am trying to do. I am just trying to get the value of #input_2_22. My code actually works but not until the second click. I will update the OP. Yes, you are correct, #input_2_22 would work just fine.

Comment: I just updated the op with some html and some more info.

Comment: Thanks but that's still not quite what I am needing. Each time a radio button is select, the #input_2_22 value is updated. So, if the input named wo1 was clicked, #input_2_22 would automatically be set to 14.99. It looks like that is getting set after my script because console.log always shows the previous value.

Comment: @user715564 updated, note that your last radio button and your last select have the same `name` attribute, Im guessing this is a typo?

Comment: This moves your "set the hidden field value" logic into the change handler, since you didnt show us that code, it's hard to know exactly what would be the best way to set that up...

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately, since I am using a wordpress plugin, the section that actually sets the hidden field value is in a completely different file. I'm having to work around a lot of js functionality that is being handled by the plugin. Not fun.

Comment: in that case, try adding a timer (updated above) so you wait 1 second before acting on the event, giving the other code time to make its changes.  Crude, but it might work in your case...

Comment: That's....perfect! So, I have one more issue. Basically, I need to the change function to fire only under a certain condition. I have updated the op.

Comment: @user715564 try the updated code, sorry for the formatting, writing code on an iPhone is not ideal

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how to present this answer as many things need to be addressed. Lets take it one line at a time, the following comments are based on the HTML provided in the question.

```
// this matches the first three radio buttons
var workOrderInput = jQuery(".work-order-select input");
// this does not match anything
var eventSchedulerInput = jQuery(".event-scheduler .gchoice_2_13_0 #choice_2_13_0");
// this matches the dropdown
var eventSchedulerSelect = jQuery(".event-scheduler select");

jQuery([workOrderInput, eventSchedulerInput, eventSchedulerSelect]).each(function() {
    jQuery(this).mouseup(function() {
        // this selector does not match anything either
        var totalCost = jQuery(".signup-cost #field_2_22 #input_2_22").val();
        console.log(totalCost);
    });
});
```

Here is a [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/wzbqvm62/5/) that illustrates the points made above.

**Now lets apply what we learned and fix a few things up.**

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
        // match radio buttons that are children of an element with the class "work-order-select"
    var workOrderInput = $(".work-order-select input[type=radio]"),
        // match radio buttons that are children of an element with the class "event-scheduler"
        eventSchedulerInput = $(".event-scheduler input[type=radio]"),
        // match a select element that is the child of an element with the class "event-scheduler"
        eventSchedulerSelect = $(".event-scheduler select"),
        // get one element with the id "input_2_22"
        hiddenInput = $("#input_2_22");

    $([workOrderInput, eventSchedulerInput, eventSchedulerSelect]).each(function() {
        this.on('change', function() {
            // get the value of the hidden element
            var totalCost = hiddenInput.val();
            // do something with it.
            alert(totalCost);
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <div class="work-order-select" style="border:1px solid black">.work-order-select input[type=radio]
        <br />
        <input type="radio" name="wo1" value="14.99" />
        <br />These two radio buttons have a different name
        <input type="radio" name="wo2" value="24.99" />
        <input type="radio" name="wo2" value="34.99" />
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="event-scheduler">
        <div style="border:1px solid black">.event-scheduler input[type=radio]
            <input type="radio" name="radio-es1" value="44.99" />
        </div>
        <br />
        <div style="border:1px solid black">.event-scheduler select
        
        <select name="select-es1">
            <option value="Square Footage|0">Square Footage</option>
            <option value="Under 50,000($29.00/mt)|29">Under 50,000($29.00/mt)</option>
            <option value="Under 75,000($49.00/mt)|49">Under 75,000($49.00/mt)</option>
            <option value="Under 100,000($59.00/mt)|59">Under 100,000($59.00/mt)</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div> <span class="total"></span>
                <input type="hidden" id="input_2_22" value="49.99" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Why would you stick with all these different selectors and not just give them all a single class and be done with it?

Comment: I am addressing the issues that exist in the question.